# Contar cuantas veces aparece un valor en SQL en la fila que estoy hacia arriba

Tags: sql

Buen dia, tengo el diguiente problema tengo esta formula en excel y necesito pasarla a SQL por el volumen de los datos:

```
IF(Q2="negativo",IF(COUNTIF(R$2:$S2,R2)<=S2,1,0),IF(COUNTIF(R$2:$S2,R2)<=S2,1,0))
```

El problema me surge en la parte:

```
COUNTIF(R$2:$S2,R2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como pueden ver unicamente me cuenta el valor [Cedula] en la fila en la que estoy y hacia arriba pero no he podido replicarlo en SQL, si pudieran por favor ayudarme

La parte del if lo hice con un case pero no he podido aterrizar la parte del countif

```
CASE WHEN Naturaleza = 'Negativo' 
       THEN (CASE WHEN /*COUNTIF(R$2:$S2,R2)*/ 
       <= [Numero de lineas duplicadas] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ELSE (CASE WHEN /*COUNTIF(R$2:$S2,R2)*/
       <= [Numero de lineas duplicadas] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END AS [Eliminar]
```

| ID Fila | STOREKEEPER_ID | Total 2 | Data a muestrear | ABS | Naturaleza | Cedula | Numero de lineas duplicadas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 47788 |  | -0.212 | 0.212 | Negativo | 0.212-Negativo | 64 |
| 2 | 47788 |  | -0.152 | 0.152 | Negativo | 0.152-Negativo | 65 |
| 3 | 75084 |  | -0.088 | 0.088 | Negativo | 0.088-Negativo | 99 |
| 4 | 63655 |  | -0.107 | 0.107 | Negativo | 0.107-Negativo | 91 |
| 5 | 47788 |  | -0.54 | 0.54 | Negativo | 0.54-Negativo | 19 |
| 6 | 47788 |  | -0.441 | 0.441 | Negativo | 0.441-Negativo | 19 |
| 7 | 63655 |  | -1.522 | 1.522 | Negativo | 1.522-Negativo | 1 |
| 8 | 62740 |  | -0.032 | 0.032 | Negativo | 0.032-Negativo | 347 |
| 9 | 75675 |  | -0.035 | 0.035 | Negativo | 0.035-Negativo | 894 |
| 10 | 45804 |  | -0.008 | 0.008 | Negativo | 0.008-Negativo | 1150 |
| 11 | 54837 |  | -0.686 | 0.686 | Negativo | 0.686-Negativo | 10 |
| 12 | 62740 |  | -0.263 | 0.263 | Negativo | 0.263-Negativo | 54 |
| 13 | 62740 |  | -0.435 | 0.435 | Negativo | 0.435-Negativo | 22 |

Comment: Para mí sería más fácil entender el problema si agregas la estructura de la tabla sql y una muestra de los datos en la pregunta. Creo, con temor a equivocarme, que podrías indicar en el query que cuente las filas cuyo ID sea menor al ID de la fila actual.

Comment: Hola @DjCrazy coloque una parte de la tabla como la tengo en sql, justo agregue la primera columna de [ID Fila] porque quize hacer lo que comentas pero no se como :(

Comment: ¿Usas algún motor de base de datos? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Uso Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: No es recomendable almacenar cálculos en la BDD, máxime si dependen del orden de los registros. Es mejor que lo obtengas en una consulta (o vista) con funciones de ventana, ej. `count(columnaX) OVER (partition by columnaY order by columnaZ)`. Para darte una respuesta concreta debes explicar mejor la lógica de cálculo y proporcionar datos de prueba con ejemplos del resultado esperado.